# Qual a maneira mais segura para testar se um atributo data-* existe?

Tags: javascript

Preciso testar se um atributo `data-*` existe em um elemento e se esse atributo está preenchido com algum valor:

```html
<input type="text" id="teste" data-validationMessage="Esse campo é obrigatório" /> <!-- Deve retornar true -->

<input type="text" id="teste" data-validationMessage="" /> <!-- Deve retornar false -->
    
<input type="text" id="teste" /> <!-- Deve retornar false -->
```

Qual a maneira mais segura de fazer essa validação com JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Só testar se o método [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) retorna algo.

Código de exemplo (mudeis os ids dos elementos pra poder executar o snippet.

```js
validaDataAttribute(document.getElementById('teste'));
validaDataAttribute(document.getElementById('teste2'));
validaDataAttribute(document.getElementById('teste3'));

function validaDataAttribute(input){
  var dataAttr = input.getAttribute('data-validationMessage');
    
  if(dataAttr){
    console.log(input.id + ' contém o atributo data-validationMessage com um valor');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste" data-validationMessage="Esse campo é obrigatório" />
<input type="text" id="teste2" data-validationMessage="" /> 
<input type="text" id="teste3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

O método que verifica se um atributo existe é o [`Element.hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute).

No entanto se deseja trabalhar com atributos `data-*` você deve usar *preferencialmente* (pois é mais fácil de trabalhar) a propriedade [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (somente leitura) que retorna um [`DOMStringMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap) com os valores dos seus atributos, por exemplo:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('teste');

console.log('Mapeando', el.dataset);
console.log('validationMessage (invalido)', el.dataset.validationMessage);
console.log('validationmessage (valido)', el.dataset.validationmessage);
console.log('track', el.dataset.track);
console.log('ignore', el.dataset.ignore);
console.log('index', el.dataset.index);
console.log('foo', el.dataset.foo);
console.log('bar', el.dataset.bar);
console.log('baz (não existe)', el.dataset.baz);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste"
   data-validationMessage="Esse campo é obrigatório"
   data-track="true"
   data-ignore="false"
   data-index="1"
   data-foo="null"
   data-bar=""
/>
```

Note que todos valores retornados são do tipo `string` e que todas propriedades foram tratadas como *lowercase*, isso ocorre porque os valores *camelCase* são "reservados" para o uso do hífen nos atributos, por exemplo:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('teste');

console.log('Mapeando', el.dataset);
console.log('validationMessage', el.dataset.validationMessage);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste"
   data-validation-message="Esse campo é obrigatório"
/>
```

Também é importante entender que para o HTML e para as funções `hasAttribute` ou `getAttribute` é irrelevante você escrever os atributos em *camelCase*, pois sempre serão tratados como *case-insensitive*:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('teste');

console.log('data-validationMessage', el.hasAttribute("data-validationMessage"));
console.log('DATA-VALIDATIONMESSAGE', el.hasAttribute("DATA-VALIDATIONMESSAGE"));
console.log('DATA-VALIDATIONMESSAGE', el.getAttribute("DATA-VALIDATIONMESSAGE"));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste"
   data-validationMessage="Esse campo é obrigatório"
/>
```

Já com `HTMLElement.dataset` existe a padronização, que faz a conversão dos nomes, aonde os atributos `dash-style` serão convertidos para chaves em `camelCase` no `DOMStringMap`, seguindo:

- Letras minúsculas serão todos os ASCII
- Letras maiúsculas de A a Z
- Removerá os prefixos `data-*` (incluindo os traços)
- Qualquer traço (`U+002D`) seguido por uma letra (ASCII) de a a z, irá remover o traço e irá colocar a letra seguida em maiúsculo
- Outros caracteres (incluindo outros traços) permanecerão inalterados

Como pode ver:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('teste');

console.log('Mapeando', el.dataset);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste"
   data-afoo-ebar-obaz="'a' a 'z' se tornarão camelCase"
   data-áfoo-ébar-óbaz="Caracteres diferentes de 'a' a 'z' não mudarão"
   data-Áfoo-Ébar-Óbaz="Caracteres diferentes de 'a' a 'z' não mudarão"
   data-&foo-%bar-*baz----="outros caracteres ASCII"
/>
```